# How do I get the return value of a c++ function in php code?

Tags: php, c++

It's a beginner question but I researched a lot and barely found anything. Many articles or examples on zend don't exist anymore and I cant really make progress so bare with me.
I'd like to get the result from an existing c++ function to use it in php code. I set up a super simple example:
My c++ code looks like the following for now:

```
#include<iostream>
int returnnumber() {

    return 4 + 2;
}

int main() {

    
    std::cout << "test";
    return 0;
}
```

and my php code looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP-Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <?php 
        $filename = "pathtofile";
        
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
                echo "the file exists, ";
        } else {
             echo "The file doesnt exist";
        }
        $output = 0;
        $output = shell_exec($filename);
        //$output = 2
        echo $output; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output for this is the `file exists, test`
However, when I remove the comments of `$output = 2` the result becomes `the file exists, 2` which I really don't understand. Why is $output my cout string value and not my return integer value from my main function, so 0 in this case? And how do I get the value 0, and additionally,how would I get the result of,in this case, `int returnnumber()` ?

Comment: `shell_exec()` returns the _output_ from the command (which is "test") and not the exit status (which is 0). If you want the exit status, then use `exec()` but note that the exit status is what `main()` returns, not what `returnnumber()` returns.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a simple way to get the return of returnnumber() ?

Comment: You're never calling it. You could just replace `return 0;` with `return returnnumber();` Note this will only work for small integers. If you need a string you'll have to capture the output.

Comment: When you remove the comments of `$output = 2` you are assigning the value of 2 to the variable `$output` and it no longer has the value from `shell_exec($filename)`.

Comment: You cannot simply invoke a function that exists in a totally different binary like this. You would have to implement some kind of API that defines how the two entities interact. In this case you either [in order of increasing difficulty] passively capture the output of the C++ app which is invoked independently [as has already been suggested], define a protocol or API for the two to actively communicate, or port the code to C and integrate it into a custom PHP extension.

Comment: Oh really? I didnt expect it to be that difficult, but thanks a lot for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php
$out = shell_exec("date > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?");
echo "result is: $out";
 ?>
```

This is how we get exit status of any command in shell. You execute the command and check the value of `$?` (and probably divide it by 256 but not in this case).